# I have allocated enough memory space, but after writing about 69 characters I get access violation

Tags: c, arrays, char

I have the following code in the calling console application. Code is written in C language

```
char list[500000];
int ret=0;
ret = GetFeatures(".", list);
```

in the dll implementation of method GetFeatures(char *PATH, char featureList[500000]).

in the code segment below the method throws an error (Access Violation) just after writing about 69 characters. Does anyone know why?

```
while (pos=0)
{   
    strcat(featureList, getFeatureName());
    strcat(featureList, "|");
    strcat(featureList, getVersion);
    strcat(featureList, "|");
    strcat(featureList, getVS());
    strcat(featureList, ";");

    pos = isEnd();
}
```

---

[update from comment:]

`pos=0` was a typo.

Comment: What's the language?

Comment: sorry it is C language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things:

Firstly, you've not initialized the memory in `list`. It could contain anything, so any attempt to use it with `strcat` is dangerous and likely to crash unpredictably.

When you declare the array, do this instead:

```
char list[500000] = "";
```

Secondly, your `while` loop should be:

```
while (pos==0)
```

Otherwise you're resetting it to 0. So the code in the `while` loop will never evaluate.

Comment: One wonders why the never-executed `strcat()` fails! Perhaps it is just a typo in the question.

Comment: Although I fully agree with and support the proposal of initialising the `char`-array before its 1st usage, for completness I'd like to mention that alternativly changeing the 1st call to `strcat()` to become a call to `strcpy()` instead would fix the issue also.

Comment: @alk: Yep, I had that in before in a previous edit - the thing is, the OP seems to be intending to iterate with the while loop - if you change the first call to `strcpy` that will reset the string each time it goes round the loop.

Comment: "*so any attempt to use it with strcat could be very problematic.*" to not say it will invoke the infamous Undefined Behaviour by reading the `char`-array's uninitialsed memory.

Comment: @Baldrick: Ah yes, sure. I missed the context of the loop. So, you are right, using `strcpy()` would **not** be an option within this context.

Comment: pos=0 was a typo; thanks for your advice on initialization applied. the reason for access violation was  that getVS() was returning NULL. I am not a C programmer and hoping will never have to write in C again, where it is so difficult to do simple things. You deserve a tick for attempting and helpful.

Comment: A better idea is only setting the first byte to `0`, instead of all 500K. There's a certain overhead to zeroing everything, and it does not seem neccessary.

Comment: @Deduplicator: For the sake of simplicity, I'd prefer uing the `...="";` initilaliser, at least if speed is not an issue.

Comment: @Warrior: No problem! Although I'm not overly delighted with your savage attack on the C language, feel free to accept the answer if you feel it helped..!  ;)  On a serious note though, C just does exactly what you tell it without trying to second-guess! Whether that's good or bad depends on your perspective!

Comment: @Deduplicator: My understanding was that the `=""` intializer pretty much translates to a 'strcpy' - so it won't fill in all 500K. Is that not correct?

Comment: @Baldrick: No, it isn't. It means, initialize with these elements and zero the rest, just like if you used a `{...}` initializer-

Comment: @Baldrick, oh don't be I am just frustrated. I am not done yet now I have to access it from C#, wish me luck.